# DelegatingHandler and HttpClient in a loop

Tags: c#, loops, dotnet-httpclient, delegatinghandler, httpclienthandler

I am trying to execute `HttpClient.GetAsync` in a loop.
As per [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client#create-and-initialize-httpclient), it is recommended to use 1 instance of `HttpClient`.

The way I'm getting `HttpClient` is

```
var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.Create(HttpClientRequestHandler.HttpMessageHandler, delegatingHandler);
```

It hits `GetAsync` function fine, the first time, but when I reuse the `httpClient` reference, I'm getting the error: `The 'DelegatingHandler' list is invalid because the property 'InnerHandler' of 'HttpClientTelemetryHandler' is not null.`

When I tried creating a new `Handler` and `HttpClient` instance in the loop everytime, it works fine.

This is now a conflict of interest. Should I create a new instance everytime in the loop, or is there any other way of doing this which is the right way to do it.

*Additional info: The custom library which I consume to create the `HttpClient` is `.Net Standard 2.0` and the client application which calls the HttpClient is `.Net Core 2.1`.*

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need to create a HttpClient this way? Could you share some code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usually this error happens when you reuse the same `Handler` instance in a batch or a loop.

Disposing the HttpClient properly at the end of each request prevents this error.

```
public class Test{
 private static HttpClient _httpClient;

 SomeFunction(){
 using (var client = new HttpClient(
       HttpClientFactory.CreatePipeline(
       new HttpClientHandler
           {
              CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
              UseCookies = true
            },
       new DelegatingHandler[] { new CustomHandler() })))
    {
         //do something with `client`
    }  

 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks HariHaran for the response. But, it seems Dispose doesn't exactly do the cleanup in case of `HttpClient`, as can be understood from this document: https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/

Comment: @AlenAlex read it again. The solution is to use `static` client. Which i have already used in the answer. Try it on your code